# Request Google Contacts After Successful Omniauth Authentication Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, omniauth, google-contacts-api

I am having trouble figuring out how to make a request to the Google Contacts API after a successful authentication.

```
provider :google_oauth2, "key", "secret", :scope => "userinfo.profile,https://www.google.com/m8/feeds", :approval_prompt => 'auto'
```

This successfully authenticates the user with permission to access the contact api.

My question is - how do I make the next request to actually get the contacts using the refresh token and other information provided by:

```
request.env['omniauth.auth']
```

I've read that you need to specify specific headers like GData-Version => 3.0 but can't seem to figure out how the entire request would look like.

Thank you!

Comment: still looking for an answer on this one?

Comment: I am actually. I found a work around but would love to know your solution if you have one.

Comment: well i can successfully get contacts using the supplied token, still trying to implement getting the refresh token once the token has expired...did you get that far?

Comment: I deconstructed the 'omnicontacts' gem and just used all the functions/methods related to fetching the contacts. Took a while to isolate the right parts but everything works. In the omniauth callback function, I run the omnicontact functions to grab contacts. The functions I extracted also handle getting the refresh token.